# ASP.NET Refrence to my local PC in users event log, why?

Tags: asp.net

A customer has sent my a screen shot of their event log which shows an error from my ASP.Net app, the problem is it shows the line number where the error occurred but references my PC and the path into my files. Why? There's no references in my code.

Thanks
Lee

Answer (score 3):

This would happen if you distribute your symbol file, which contains source paths.

If you don't distribute the PDB files, there will not be any source information.

Answer (score 2):

Your application must be deployed with the pdb files in the bin directory. The pdb file will have references to the source file and pc that compiled it